# How to make a fake usb device or make a device appear as another device

Tags: linux, usb, iot, libusb, usbserial

I have an android phone which shows up correctly when running 
`lsusb -t` and I can also see its serial ID when running `lsusb -v |fgrep -i iserial` I would like this device to show up with a specific serial id so that another application can connect to it.

Is there any way to mock or proxy a device serial ID so that another application can connect to it ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible with changing sources of the Linux kernel USB driver on this system where you connect your Android to. It will need some research in Linux kernel sources, do some modification and recompilation of kernel.